# Data Validation Problems In Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to create a form, but I'm facing some challenges.
Registration Number should start with an R and have max of 13 characters e.g R1234567891234. I was able to use custom data validation `=EXACT(LEFT(D5,2), "R-")`
to enforce it starting with R but not for character length.

Then I want some cells(J2:M2) to be un-fillable until others(E2:H2) have text in them. But the problem is that (J2:M2) & (E2:H2) already have this formula/variations of this formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK($I2),"",IF(TODAY()>$I$2+183,"Exam due",""))
```

in them

I tried using this

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(L2),ISBLANK(F2),ISBLANK(G3),ISBLANK(H4)),"NEY",IF(ISBLANK($I2),"",IF(TODAY()>$I$2+183,"Exam due","")))
```

But it doesn't work cause (J2:M2) & (E2:H2) have data validations in them that allows the cells to accept only whole numbers.

So how can I retain the numeric data validation for (J2:M2) & (E2:H2) and still have it to be un-fillable if previous cells are still blank?

Comment: I need some clarity.

1) Registration numbers, do you mean that the characters following the R cannot exceed 13, to a max cell length of 14?

2) Do you need it unfillable if the entire array is blank or only if a corresponding cell is blank (such as E2 is unfillable if J2 is blank)?

3) Why can't you just leave it as formula such that it is blank if the corresponding cell is blank and filled otherwise?

Comment: 1) Yes the max cell length should be 14, but starting with "R". 2)I need it unfillable if the entire array is blank. 3) I don't really understand the third question.

Answer (score 0):

For the registration number:

=AND(LEFT(D5,1)="R",LEN(D5)<15)

For the data Validation:

=AND(SUMPRODUCT(ISFORMULA(G2:J2)*1)=0,ROUND(SUM(L2:O2),0)=SUM(L2:O2))

Comment: The second one assumes that the user will overwrite the formula when filling out the box and not put in a new formula.